# In a npm package, how to add vscode plugin suggest?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I has a npm package and a vscode snippet plugin, when user install this npm package, how to suggest my vscode plugin, where is documents

Comment: You need to post the contents from your `package.json` file, in the form of a code block. You need to inform us what the plugin's name is, a link to the NPM location would also be helpful. And you need to be more verbose when you ask a question, give us something to think about. Try to remember that we (the stack overflow community) are not present at your physical location, we don't know what your doing at all, and we can't see what your doing either, therefore; when you ask a question you need to put forth some brevity, explain yourself like your talking to a stupid person (seriously).

Comment: I only need that document